# Is there a way to make my (Next) button displaying questions every time a user clicks on it?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a quiz application that displays a question every time a user clicks on the (next) button, But all my attempts failed, I'll share my lines of code below

```js
let Qustions = [{
  question1 :"What is 2+8 ? ",
  question2:" How many legs does the spider have ? ",
  question3 : " what is the capital of Russia ?",
}]

let display = document.querySelector('h3');
let btn = document.getElementById('next');

btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  display.innerText = Qustions[0].question1;
  display.innerText = Qustions[0].question2;
  display.innerText = Qustions[0].question3;
  
})
```

```css
.container{
  background-color: lightblue;
  width:400px;
  margin:10em auto;
  padding:20px;
}
h3{
  text-align:center;
}
h2{
  float:right;
  position:absolute;
  top:219px;
  right:750px;
  border-radius:10px;
}
#next{
  width:100px;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  border-style:none;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Quiz</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
     <h3>Qustions will be displayed here</h3>
     <button id ="next" value ="submit"> Next</button>
    <h2 id ="score"></h2>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

what I have tried Also is to create a function that calls the questions i have, but it was always going to the last question and display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing here is basically overwrite the `display.innertText` with question3 every time.

```
 btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  display.innerText = Qustions[0].question1;
  display.innerText = Qustions[0].question2;
  display.innerText = Qustions[0].question3;
})
```

What you should do instead is to have a `counter = 0` and when the user click next button, you increase the counter by one.
Also, you should not store your question in that format. You should use array of string instead.

The entire javascript code should be:

```
const QUESTIONS = [
   "What is 2+8?", 
   "How many legs does the spider have?", 
   "what is the capital of Russia?"
];

let counter = 0;
let display = document.querySelector('h3');
display.innerText = QUESTIONS[counter]

let btn = document.getElementById('next');

btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
   counter++;
   display.innerText = QUESTIONS[counter]
})
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you ! That was exactly what I needed ;)